# Python multiprocessing avoid global variables

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

My handbrake compressor uses a multiprocessing queue to store movies to compress. In my main class I call a process which gets an queue element if exists. These process spawn another process which calls then a subprocess that calls handbrake. After that in the first process a second process will be called which reads the actual stdout of handbrake. That works very well.

Now I want to write the state (processing, waiting, finished) and the progress to a global variable. I need this, because later, I will implement an xml-rpc interface. Over this interface it should be possible to get the status of each compress thread.

Global variables are bad style, and I read, that there is something I do wrong, when I have to use it. But I don't know how I can make it right?
I have also a sqlite3 db, where I can store the progress. If I implement a web gui later I don't like to call the db file directly, I want my application to do this.

Comment: Have you looked into [Managers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)?

Comment: I've read this now, but they are also kind of global variables, or?